# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

Tags: python, urllib

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import random
import re

random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

def getLinks(articleUrl):
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org"+articleUrl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return bsObj.find("div", {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll("a",href = re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))

getLinks('http://en.wikipedia.org')
```

OS is Linux.  The above script spits out a "urllib.error.URLError: ".  Looked through a number of attempts to solve this that I found on google, but none of them fixed my problem (attempted solutions include changing the env variable and adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 to my resolv.conf file).

Comment: Other than the fact that you haven't figured out what the first line of the function is doing?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh boy do I feel stupid now.  I had just put that in there to "test" the script before writing the rest of it, but when I tried it with an actual wikipedia article, it stopped giving the URL error.   Thank you!

Comment: what's the value of `articleUrl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `getLinks()` with a valid url:

```
>>> getLinks('/wiki/Main_Page')
```

Besides, in your function, you should also call `.read()` to get the response content before passing it to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org" + articleUrl).read()
```